# Run PHP files from Javascript to check Online users: says users who are not logged in are

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, session

I am writing just a simple admin panel but want to enable users who are logged in to see other logged in users. To do this, I have a sessions MySQL table which contains the active sessions (logged in users) and a PHP file which essentially will update the timestamp of each active user every few seconds using JavaScript on all pages (so it will only update if active and will delete sessions that are greater than 30 seconds ago). Here is the code for that:

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function track() {
var url = "tracking.php?username=<?PHP echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>";
xmlReq=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlReq.open("GET",url,true);
xmlReq.send();
}
setInterval(function(){track();}, 3000);
</script>
```

PHP: So the url would be tracking.php?username=john.doe

```
<?PHP
$username=$_GET['username'];
if($username){
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE username='$username'");

if(mysql_fetch_array($result) !== false){
mysql_query("UPDATE sessions SET time=now() WHERE username='$username'");
} else {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `sessions` (`username`, `time`) VALUES ('$username',now())") or die (mysql_error());
}
mysql_query("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE time < (now() - 30);");
}
?>
```

This works fine and the session table updates every 3 seconds. The problem is when I come to display which users are currently logged in. I have a check.php file which contains the following:

```
<?PHP
$username=$_GET['username'];
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE username = '$username'");
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($num>0){
echo "Online";
} else {
echo "Offline";
}
?>
```

And the Javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checklogin(username) {
var element = "status";
newusername = username.substring(0, username.indexOf('.'));
newelement = element + newusername;
$.ajax({
url: ‘check.php?username='+username,
type: "GET",
dataType: "html",
success: function(data)
{
if(data === "Online")
{
document.getElementById(newelement).innerHTML='<div class="online"></div>';
}
}
});
}
</script>
```

Which would change the div of the user:

```
<?PHP
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_admin_users order by id ASC");
$num=mysql_num_rows($sql);
$i=0;
while($num>$i){
$id=mysql_result($sql,$i,"id");
$username=mysql_result($sql,$i,"username");
$first_name=mysql_result($sql,$i,"firstname");
$last_name=mysql_result($sql,$i,"lastname");
$jobtitle=mysql_result($sql,$i,"jobtitle");
$email=mysql_result($sql,$i,"email");
$phone=mysql_result($sql,$i,"phone_office");
$spanar=explode(".",$username);
$spanid=$spanar[0];
?>

<tr>
<td class="center" width="40px">
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function(){checklogin('<?PHP echo $username; ?>');}, <?PHP echo rand(2000,4000); ?>);
</script>
<span id="status<?PHP echo $spanid?>"></span>
</td>
```

Now everything seems to be working fine apart from over time other users who are not active and are not in the session table are being displayed as online. For the life of me I am unable to see where the problem is. Is it with the javascript or the PHP checking the DB?

Could the file be running on the server in the background once run and it picks up the previous running of the check.php which was online and moving it onto the other user? Do I need to close the file after retrieving the online/offline? I have tried to ensure that the time the file is run is randomised so as not to run at the same time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you try SQL NO CACHE on the SELECT and report back the result?
More information here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-cache-in-select.html
I would also advise that sending that request every 3 seconds seems like overkill. With a lot of users that's gonna cause trouble. Never mind the processing on the client side if you decide to do anything with the response.

Comment: Thanks Askanison4, I will do the nocache anyway and lengthen the time.

Comment: Did you try to add an else part to remove 'online' class: <div class="online"></div>

Comment: @mali303 That's a good spot. OP, you should try this.

Comment: @ColumKelly have you tried that fix?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your Javascripts are getting cached responses.
disable caching on the PHP files.

Use headers in you php:

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
?>
```

Comment: I also concur with the overkill of 3 seconds. It will not work with many users online at the same time. Make sure to stress test your app.

Comment: I tried putting the code in as you have but seems to not work. I have tried to put the time the script runs to 1/2 minutes at random and i have left it open for 10 minutes and it seems to have worked as only myself appears logged in at the moment. So as a rule of thumb i would be better off check the sessions table with PHP on load then run the check in longer intervals?

Comment: why don't you get the whole online/offline status within 1 query? Its bad practice to query for each user individually. change your algorithm to get all user on/off line status every 30 seconds by querying the db and returning the current online/offline users list.